# EXPECT_CALL of googlemock leads to "unknown file:error: SEH exception with code 0xc0000005 thrown in the test body"

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, mocking, googlemock

I am novice to googlemock. My current project needs googlemock to use. I have learned from basics of gmock from google help site. But when I have tried to implement the same in my project it threw `SEH exception with code 0xc0000005` error.
My project has multiple threads, one of the thread call RUN_ALL_TESTS
The above code leads to `SEH exception`

tools: VS2010, windows 7

`Try to mock the function of a class`

```
using ::testing::Return;
using ::testing::Test;
using ::testing::NiceMock;

class OsInterfaceCPP
{  

public: 

    OsInterfaceCPP(void){};
    virtual ~OsInterfaceCPP(void){};
    virtual int add_test(int a, int b) = 0;
    int calladdtest(int aa, int bb)
    {
        return add_test(aa,bb);
    }
};  
class OsCPPApis : public OsInterfaceCPP 
{  
public: 
    OsCPPApis(void){};
    virtual ~OsCPPApis(void){};
    virtual int add_test(int aa, int bb)
    {
        return (aa+bb);
    }
};

class MockedOSCPPApis : public  OsCPPApis
{
public:
    MockedOSCPPApis(void){};
    virtual ~MockedOSCPPApis(void){};
    MOCK_METHOD2(add_test, int(int aaa, int bbb));
};


OSapiTestFunc::OSapiTestFunc(void){}

OSapiTestFunc::~OSapiTestFunc(void){}

void OSapiTestFunc::SetUp(){}

void OSapiTestFunc::TearDown(){}

void OSapiTestFunc::RunTests()
{
    int argc=0;
    char **argv = 0;
    ::testing::InitGoogleMock(&argc, argv); 

}

TEST_F(OSapiTestFunc, OS_Test1)
{

    OsCPPApis TestOscppapis;
    MockedOSCPPApis Testmockosapi;
    int a, b;
    a = 2;
    b = 5;
    bool test1var = true;
    EXPECT_CALL(Testmockosapi,add_test(a, b));

    TestOscppapis.add_test(5,3);
}
```

Comment: Why do you inherit `MockedOSCPPApis` from `OsCPPApis` and not from the `OsInterfaceCPP`? As far I can see, there's nothing to mock from `OsCPPApis` it implements `add_test()`.

Answer (score 6):

0xC0000005 is a "you accessed memory that doesn't exist". I can't see exactly where in your code this happens right now. But that's definitely what goes wrong. You may want to run with a debugger and see where it thinks it goes wrong.

Answer (score 3):

The only point I'd supect to be the reason for a (most probably) NULL pointer access is

```
void OSapiTestFunc::RunTests()
{
    int argc=0;
    char **argv = 0;
    ::testing::InitGoogleMock(argc, argv); 
}
```

Usually when this is called from a `main()` function as intended, at least `argv` never would be NULL because the first argument always contains the executable name.

**UPDATE:**
Note my edit how `argc` is passed! Simply the **value** not the **address**!

Comment: Could please elaborate more? Because when I run the program with `Gmock` I too did get the same error.

Comment: @RasmiRanjanNayak Then it might be a problem with the `MockedOSCPPApis` class implementation as I mentioned in my comment on the question.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ How will this work? `InitGoogleMock` excepcts an **&int** and the path as arguments.